# How to take the config.XML field value based on property file value in shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, xml

**I have an XML file called config.xml**

```
<builders>
    <hudson.tasks.Shell>
      <command>$RA_CHEKOUT_SHELL_COMMAND</command>
    </hudson.tasks.Shell>
  </builders>
```

**Here is my property file content**

**build.prop**

This is to check out the job from Jenkins.
here we are going to perform checkout operation.

**Shell script**

Here I am reading the property file line by line and assign the property file values into a variable and used the value in config.xml file field.

```
file="/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Env-inject-example2/build.prop"
counter=1

while IFS= read line
do
    # display $line 
    echo "Text read from file: $line" 
    counter=`expr $counter + 1`
    name=$(cat "$file") 
    echo $name 
    echo "Change values in config.xml..."
done <"$file"
cat <<EOF 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
   <builders>
    <hudson.tasks.Shell>
      <command>$name</command>
    </hudson.tasks.Shell>
  </builders>
</config>
EOF  
echo "Done."
```

**Note:** Now I have used the config.xml within the shell script to change the field value but I want to use the shell variable outside config.xml file.How should I represent the path and How should I inject the values to the config.xml file.

Comment: So do you simply want to check the properties of a file with a command and replace the output from the command with this line?

Comment: Hi, @ADDB thanks... could u pls see my above-edited question I have got the solution but I want to do it in an outside config.xml file pls refer the above question

Comment: So with your solution your creating a new config.xml, but your goal is to edit the old one? Also what do you mean by represent the path?

Comment: yes, you are right, I said the path becoz ..I have my old config.xml file in different folder so from the shell script I have to change the config.xml file field value

Comment: Hmmm instead of using the cat command to create a new file with $name as input, you can use the sed command that is described in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed "s@PatternThatShouldBeReplaced@$name" /Path/To/config.xml
```

Note: sed seperator normally is / but I suggest @ in this case for allowing the variable to include / without escaping